# SQLite3 there's no such SavePoint when rolling back

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two functions

```
def set_Savepoint():
    db.execute("savepoint t1bis")
    

def rollback_to_sp():
    db.execute("rollback to savepoint t1bis")
```

The first one creates a SavePoint and the second one restores the save point.
But unfortunately, every time I call the rollback functions it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 194, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 189, in main
    operaciones_bbdd.rollback_to_sp()
  File "/Users/yunhaolin/Documents/GitHub/DDSI-C1_5/Database_DDSI/operaciones_bbdd.py", line 485, in rollback_to_sp
    db.execute("rollback to savepoint t1bis")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such savepoint: t1bis
```

Here is how I am calling it from the main:

```
operaciones_bbdd.set_Savepoint()
some operations
operaciones_bbdd.rollback_to_sp()
```

(operaciones_bbdd is the file where those operations are declared)

I don't see the reason why this is not working, trying to use the commands manually in SQLite3 command line, works fine. Also I tried to use *db.isolation_level = None* and ended up throwing the same error

In the error message, it says there's no such SavePoint, but I have clearly created the t1bis sp, right?

Comment: That error message shows your rollback method taking an argument, which your posted code doesn't. You need to give us a [mcve].

Comment: Is autocommit on?

Comment: I'm don't seem to find how to disable auto commit in python